# Connect to dev_appserver Datastore using Python protocol buffers library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a python script that add some entities to Cloud Datastore Local Development Server using Python protocol buffers library, and I would like to:

1. Instead of using Cloud Datastore Local Development use
   dev_appserver datastore

or

2. Make somehow dev_appserver use datastore file created by Cloud
   Datastore Local Development Server

I know there is an option to set the datastore file:
 --datastore-path DATASTORE_PATH
        Path to a file used to store datastore contents

But I couldn't make it work.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: `dev_appserver` uses a `sqlite` file format and stores data in a special format that it understands. I doubt it would be compatible with the output of the Cloud Datastore dev server. Why do you need to switch from Cloud Datastore to the app engine datastore? That information may help you get a better answer.

Comment: These Cloud Datastore entities are the result of a compute process made on compute engine. So the idea is to be able to view them using appengine.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported, but there is an open feature request:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/21

You can follow that issue for updates.

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow up that.